# Error Message NSData

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdata, rtf

I need to display an `RTF file` in a `UITextView`. My code looks like below:

**My .h file:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *creditsTextView;
```

**My .m file**

```
@synthesize creditsTextView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSData *creditsData = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Credits" ofType:@"rtf"];

    NSAttributedString *attrString;
    NSDictionary *docAttributes;

    attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                  initWithRTF: creditsData documentAttributes: &docAttributes];
}
```

This code gives me the following **Error messages:**

at

```
*creditsData : Incompatible pointer types 'NSData *' with expression of type 'NSString *'
```

and at

```
initWithRTF : No visible @interface for 'NSAttributedString' declares the selector 'initWithRTF:documentAttributes:'
```

How can I fix these two errors?

Comment: What does `[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` return then?  It's certainly not the contents of `Credits.rtf`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:` returns type `NSString`, see [NSBundle Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIBAHJF), so you cannot directly assign NSData with `NSString`, so you can pass the returned URL to NSData with a different initialiser.

And `NSAttributedString` does not have an init method called `initWithRTF`. These are why you are seeing the errors.

Answer (score 3):

This method:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Credits" ofType:@"rtf"];
```

Returns the path were your file is.

If, after you have the path, you want to read the file, use this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
```

Find the documentation here:

[NSBundle Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSData Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also, there's no method called InitWithRTF in NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could fix the first error. However, I got the code for the `initWithRTF`from here: [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/CreatingAttributedStrings.html)

Comment: Yeah but that method is for Cocoa (OS X), not for iOS, sorry

Comment: the `initWithRTF`should work in iOS too: [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/RTFAndAttrStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000164-BBCBJIBC)

Comment: Yes but not with that method, that mehtod is exclusive for OSX